# There are too many notifications when you come to a site

Tags: discussion, status-completed, notifications, notification-bar

This is bonkers:
[image]

1. Stack Exchange message counter
2. Stack Overflow popup notification bar
3. Mailbox icon

And I see this basically every day! It's not like I haven't visited the site in six months and I **need** the notification bar to tell me something has changed, **I GET IT**.

**Suggestion**: Lose the popup notification bar if item count < 20, or if last visit date < 1 week, or if it's toggled off manually in a preference option somewhere.

The Stack Exchange message count indicator I'm okay with as well as the mailbox icon, since they're subdued, unlike the popup notification bar, which repops on ever page I visit until I look at my favorites.

It's very frustrating.

Comment: I don't agree - I'm very happy with the notifications - so -1, but +1 for the freehand circle sad face = +-0.

Comment: Well the favorite one get's annoying if it's on one of the infamous CW questions

Comment: I agree. Given the stack exchange counter, do we need pop-ups?

Comment: +1 I agree 100 percent, I thought I was the only one who noticed this.  Didn't Joel write some book about interfaces cause he needs to apply that book to the site...it's awful

Comment: Although I think "awful" may be a bit too strong, I would say that the notification bar messages(3) could easily be merged into the SE notification counter(1). Perhaps the "mailbox icon" could be merged into the account pages?

Comment: Damn those are nice circles!

Comment: noooooooooooooooo I liked having the banner on the sites I hadn't visited in a while to remind me that I may have skipped the inbox notification in the interim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items #2 and #3 are no longer present, basically, so this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy if popups didn't appear on question pages, especially if I've already visited the site that day.  The main page and profile pages could continue to be 'busy' if needed.